# PolyBase :: Changed database context to 'DWQueue'

Tags: sql-server, polybase

I'm installing PolyBase on the latest SQL Server 2019.

During the installation I'm incurring in this error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oxd8yeiBfig (sorry for the video quality)

```
The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database. 
Changed database context to 'DWQueue'.
```

Yes, this error has already been addressed here:

[SQL Server 2019 Polybase installation error "The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/296176/sql-server-2019-polybase-installation-error-the-proposed-new-database-owner-is)

This means to me that Administrators cannot install PolyBase.

Is there any way out without dropping my `Administrator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only administrators can install features to the SQL Server.
All the information should be in the summary_xxxx.txt and the other log files located in

> c:\program files\microsoft sql server\150\setup
> bootstrap\log\20220617_120543\

but the workaround in the other post holds.
Wait for the error to pop up. Connect to the SQL Server using SSMS and drop your user from the DWQueue database

```
USE DWQueue
GO
DROP USER [DOMAIN\YOURUSENAME]
GO
```

Go back to the setup and click retry and then do the same for the DWConfiguration and DWDiagnostics databases if the same error pops up there.